# In TFS 2013 Build, where exactly does "Copy build output to server" save the .zip file?

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

When creating a build definition, the "Build Defaults" section lets you specify the staging location for the build.

It has 3 options:

1. This build does not copy output files to a drop folder.
2. Copy build output to following drop folder (UNC Path, etc...)
3. Copy build out to the server.

My question is in regards to choosing option 3.

Where exactly does the ".zip" file get saved??  In the database? On the build server? Where can I see this file?

Comment: The general jist of it, it goes back into source control - http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-build/

Comment: @kidshaw Do you know if there is a way for me to see it in Source Control Explorer? Or does it just create a "hidden" location for them?

Comment: It does not go to source control.  It goes to the file container service in TFS or VSO and that is a Pathy store for unversioned items.  There is no physical zip file, each file is uploaded and the zip is built on the fly.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Interesting, do you happen to have a link with more info on this file container service?

Comment: Sorry should have said file control really. The artical shows how it can be downloaded from web UI for tfs but I don't know anymore than that.

Answer (score 1):

The files are stored in a unversioned store inside of TFS. The days is inside the SQL database so you will need to allocate the space there.

Answer (score 0):

That's no idea but if you chhose 2nd option (copying to spefic folder) then you already know the path (server share path).

For the 3rd option though you can choose `Download drop as zip` button which will let you download the saved zip file from the server location.

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm aware the 2nd option lets me explicitly specify where it gets saved and with option 3 you can just download the drop as a zip from the TFS site. however, i need to know exactly where that zip file is stored so i can know where to allocate enough resources to store all of the builds without affecting performance.

Comment: I am afraid, that information probably not present in MSDN doc as well. At least I haven't seen.

Comment: Yeah. I've been searching everywhere and can't seem to find any specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This will be stored inside file container in TFS,we can access using this container programatically using TFS web API's